# Hide youtube private controls for selling videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I would like to hide to make youtube video's private and hide the controls so I would be able to sell courses online on my platform using youtube. What is the best way to do it? Is possible to do in a way that other users won't be able to share the link with others?
It would show only the progress bar on the bottom

Comment: I would just private the course videos and sell the connecting links. This way they can only be accessed if purchased. This does, however, leave the issue of third-party redistribution. Maybe you could make some sort of timer, where you delete the video after 24 hours or something. This could reduce the incentive for reselling, but it would make it tedious to sell to a large quantity of buyers. Sorry if not the most helpful, just brainstorming...

Comment: @Kai thanks for the idea, that is a good idea. Can you upvote the question, so more people will see it? :)